# .net does not see staticfiles when connecting https to nginx

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have a problem with the connected https protocol on the DotNet project.

I created a certificate on the cloudflare service, uploaded it to my VPS server,
however, if earlier when opening the site by Ip address, the site opened normally

http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

but when connecting to https://example.com I get a 404 error on static files located in the wwwroot directory.

Server: 
Linux Ubuntu 18.04,
nginx,
DotNet

I have standard project settings

Startup.cs

```cs
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

Program.cs

```cs
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseUrls("http://*:9580")
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

is the error I get, 
but on http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx it works fine.

Comment: Missing info: have you updated your DNS settings based on the Clouldflare setup? **If** you can successfully get to your site _by IP_, then your CF/DNS settings is where I'd look first.

Comment: in cloudflare I added of course in DNS management a record about a name and IP, when now i try to login via ip http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx i get redirect to example.com

Comment: updated dns records in the domain registration service